# Read properties from Maven POM with SBT

Tags: maven, sbt

I have an SBT build file that contains some dependencies with versions that I would like to read out of a Maven POM file. This POM file contains entries like

```
<properties>
  <libx.version>1.21.0</libx.version>
  <liby.version>1.29.1</liby.version>
</properties>
```

My SBT file contains dependencies like

```
libraryDependencies += "org.example" % "libx" % "1.21.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.example" % "liby" % "1.29.1"
```

Keeping the versions in sync is quite cumbersome. What is the most elegant way to make SBT parse them out of the POM file?